# What is the best practice for calling the same function multiple different times

Tags: python, function, loops

New to Python and I am attempting to write something that will take files located in different directories and unzip them (*.Z files). I'm trying to understand the best way of doing this without repeating code as below. However, other than adding the same line again for each file can this be looped somehow for each file name? For instance one file may reside in /root/xxx/yyy.Z  another /root/xxx/zzz.Z  and /root/xxx/aaa.Z

I can run this function with arguments pointing to each directory, but this feels clunky but works.

```
def UnzipFiles(pathtofile1,pathtofile2,pathtofile3):
    for filename in os.listdir(pathtofile1):
        if filename.endswith(".Z"): 
           retcode = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile1])
    else:
        if retcode != 0:
            raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode)

    for filename in os.listdir(pathtofile2):
        if filename.endswith(".Z"): 
           retcode = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile1])
    else:
        if retcode != 0:
            raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode)

    for filename in os.listdir(pathtofile3):
        if filename.endswith(".Z"): 
           retcode = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile3])
    else:
        if retcode != 0:
            raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode)
```

I must make a few things clear that I didn't in my original post.   (1) Groups of .Z files are their own directory  For instance one group of files reside in /root/xxx/yyy.Z another /root/yyy/zzz.Z and /root/aaa/aaa.Z . So there are three different directories that I need to cycle through.  And (2)  There are approximately 20 or so files that are being unzipped. And this activity will happen at best monthly.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code for 1 input file and check os walk() after that you can pass list of filees using `map()`

```
results = list(map(UnzipFiles, [list of files]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip function in python to iterate 3 variables at the same time

```
def UnzipFiles(pathtofile1,pathtofile2,pathtofile3):
    for filename1,filename2,filename3 in zip(os.listdir(pathtofile1),os.listdir(pathtofile2),os.listdir(pathtofile3)):
        if filename1.endswith(".Z"): 
            retcode1 = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile1])
        else:
            if retcode1 != 0:
               raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode1)
        if filename2.endswith(".Z"): 
            retcode2 = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile2])
        else:
            if retcode2 != 0:
               raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode2)
        if filename3.endswith(".Z"): 
            retcode3 = subprocess.call(['gunzip', pathtofile3])
        else:
           if retcode3 != 0:
               raise IOError('unzipfiles exited with code %d' % retcode3)
```

This is essentially the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It seems premature to make this into a function--it's hardcoded to work only on 3 "file" parameters and even if that's modified to be one parameter, it's still tied down to the `".Z"` extension. This makes it essentially useful for only one ultra-specific task: unzipping *exactly* 3 files (really directories...) with a specific extension.

Also, there seems to be confusion between directories and file paths; `os.listdir` pulls in all files in a directory, which seems contrary to how you've named your variables, which suggest that you're passing in file paths.

Either way, you can remove the multiple blocks in your function and pass in the root folder to the path, or, conversely, skip `os.listdir` and give a direct, single path to `subprocess.call`.

I'd suggest writing the code inline:

```
for path in os.listdir('/root/xxx/'):
    if path.endswith('.Z') and ret := subprocess.call(['gunzip', path]):
        raise IOError(f'gunzip exited with code {ret} on {path}')
```

If you're really doing this so frequently that this is too much clutter for the caller, you can use:

```
def unzip_all(directory, extension='.Z'):
    for path in os.listdir(directory):
        if path.endswith(extension) and ret := subprocess.call(['gunzip', path]):
            raise IOError(f'gunzip exited with code {ret} on {path}')
```

And if you only want to extract 3 specific files rather than 3 specific directories:

```
for path in ['root/xxx/foo.Z', 'root/xxx/bar.Z', 'root/xxx/baz.Z']:
    if ret := subprocess.call(['gunzip', path]):
        raise IOError(f'gunzip exited with code {ret} on {path}')
```

Since `gunzip` accepts multiple arguments, you could take advantage of that to boil the whole thing down to:

```
paths = ['root/xxx/foo.Z', 'root/xxx/bar.Z', 'root/xxx/baz.Z']

if ret := subprocess.call(['gunzip'] + paths):
    raise IOError(f'gunzip exited with code {ret} on {paths}')
```

Note that this uses the whisker assignment syntax `:=` in Python 3.8.

As an aside,

```
else:
    if:
        ....
```

is a more complicated way of writing

```
elif:
    ....
```

I recommend following [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); functions should be `lower_camel_case`. `UpperCamelCase` is reserved for classes.